# Is it safe to use http inside service fabric cluster for service to service commiunication?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I created a secure service fabric and have full control. Only services developed by me will be deployed and all public facing apis are using https. The question is for communication between service to service in cluster, is it safe to use http instead of https?

Thanks,

Comment: Its more a question about where the service fabric cluster is. If its in Azure, the nodes can each be anywhere so its iffy. If its local, then nothing should be leaving your building so not a big deal. If you don't want the trouble of ssl certificates, why not just TDES or AES encrypt the payload being sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to how do you set up your cluster with your network. Public facing services and internal services should be in a different NSG networks. You should control very strict communication between public and internal. If you can do that then http or any protocol between services is not a problem

Personally, i prefer http over remoting because there will be less dependency between services. Communication between services can be defined using Open API and therefore become vendor neutral.

There is a very good course on MVA for how to set up Service fabric class and best practice

https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/16925?l=E5B3nJSGD_805167344

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using service fabric remoting (instead of http). This can be secured using certificates, with little effort.

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-secure-communication

Comment: Is it recommended to secure internal communication? If so - why? @LoekD

Comment: Layers of defense against Spoofing, Tampering and Information disclosure.